# How an application user should get a JWT token?

Tags: authentication, jwt, worker

1. I have several worker services that are running background tasks.
2. I have an Identity Service that authenticates and create JWT tokens.
3. The worker services need to consume REST API's that are authorized through the JWT tokens (step 2).
4. **My problem:** I need to authenticate the worker service at the Identity Service in order to get a valid JWT token so that it can consume the REST API's.

What is the best solution for this problem?

- The authentication of the worker service should be a traditional user/password login, just like any "human" user?

*OR*

- The worker service authenticates with an API Key and receives a JWT token with all the predefined roles? In this case, functionalities like the refresh token doesn't make sense, right?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement Client Credentials Flow. Your client has to be configured to allow this kind of flow. First read this:

https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/client-credentials-flow

Comment: That's correct, and to add to that, as per your question: you don't need a refresh token, you just use the Client Credentials Grant to request a new JWT when needed.